# Python shell restarts on urlopen()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, steam, urlopen

Earlier this year, I made a python 3.7.0 script that modifies my Steam profile picture. It worked great, provided I copied/pasted the `sessionid`, `steamLogin`, and `steamLoginSecure` cookies from my browser.

Lately, I wanted to automate obtaining these cookies, so I added a simple function using [ValvePython](https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to log in and return the cookies:

```
def GetCookies():
    client = SteamClient()
    client.cli_login()
    webCookies = client.get_web_session_cookies()
    if webCookies == None:
        raise Exception("Unable to get web session. Try again later.")
    return {"steamLogin": webCookies.get("steamLogin"),
        "steamLoginSecure": webCookies.get("steamLoginSecure"),
        "sessionid": str(client.session_id),
        "steamid": str(client.steam_id)}
```

But now there's a problem. My script works great, but now the script restarts when it hits one of the two `urlopen` commands later in the script. I didn't have this issue before adding this function, and it only fails on `urlopen` commands that come after the function is called, and the specific line it fails on varies.

In IDLE, it says "RESTART: Shell". There're no errors that I can see or catch. On cmd, it just closes without writing anything before close. I tried running the script in an online debugger, and it works without fail.

What could be the reason for the script just restarting without an error? Is there some process in `GetCookies()` that is too much to handle or something? How can I go about figuring out why the script is restarting?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to try moving the `client = SteamClient()` outside of the function. Create it at the start of your script, and re-use it for all subsequent connections. Objects without references are garbage collected (such as when moving out of scope).

Comment: IPython often shows more helpful info on a crash than vanilla python.  You could install it, enter an IPython shell, and then invoke your script with `%run <scriptname>`.  With any luck you'll learn something.

Another option to get more info is to `import pdb` and `pdb.set_trace()` right before the `urlopen` commands, and step through until the exit occurs.

Comment: @mfitzp I don't wanna use `client` outside of the function, so that's why I left it inside. I'll move it outside, though, and see if that helps.

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrService I'll try those and see if I can find out more. Thanks!